# Hive, JDBC, TTransportException: SASL authentication not complete

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, sasl

I connect to Hive and get id's of my data from row of table. Problems does not happens, when I connect to hive, send request and get response. But when i get id's from ResultSet i get an exception: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: SASL authentication not complete. Why does this exception arise and what needs to be done to avoid it? Sorry for my bad english.

It's my subsidiary class to create hive connection and send requests:

```
public class HiveDataSearcher implements AutoCloseable {
private static final String hiveDriverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

static {
    try {
        Class.forName(hiveDriverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private Connection hiveConnection;

private String tableName;
private String whereBody;

public HiveDataSearcher(String url, String login, String password) {
    try {
        hiveConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    this.tableName = "";
    this.whereBody = "";
}

public HiveDataSearcher(Connection hiveConnection) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(hiveConnection, "hiveConnection");

    this.hiveConnection = hiveConnection;

    this.tableName = "";
    this.whereBody = "";
}

public String getTableName() {
    return tableName;
}

public HiveDataSearcher setTableName(String tableName) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(tableName, "tableName");

    this.tableName = tableName;

    return this;
}

public String getWhereBody() {
    return whereBody;
}

public HiveDataSearcher setWhereBody(String whereBody) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(whereBody, "whereBody");

    this.whereBody = whereBody;

    return this;
}

public ResultSet select(String ... selectParams) {
    return select(Arrays.asList(selectParams));
}

public ResultSet select(Iterable<String> selectParams) {
    String request = prepareRequest(selectParams);
    ResultSet response;

    try {
        response = hiveConnection
                .createStatement()
                .executeQuery(request);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return response;
}

private String prepareRequest(Iterable<String> selectParams) {
    return new StringBuilder()
            .append("select").append(' ').append(selectParamsToHiveFormat(selectParams)).append(' ')
            .append("from").append(' ').append(tableName).append(' ')
            .append("where").append(' ').append(whereBody)
            .toString();
}

private String selectParamsToHiveFormat(Iterable<String> selectParams) {
    StringBuilder formattedSelectParams = new StringBuilder();

    for (String selectedParam : selectParams) {
        formattedSelectParams.append('\'').append(selectedParam).append('\'').append(',');
    }

    if (formattedSelectParams.length() == 0) {
        formattedSelectParams.append('*');
    } else {
        formattedSelectParams.deleteCharAt(formattedSelectParams.length() - 1);
    }

    return formattedSelectParams.toString();
}

public void close() {
    if (hiveConnection != null) {
        try {
            hiveConnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //nothing to do, just close connection
        } finally {
            hiveConnection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the code in which i connect to hive:

```
private static final String HIVE_URL = <hive url>;
private static final String HIVE_LOGIN = <hive login>;
private static final String HIVE_PASSWORD = <hive password>;

private static final String[] SEARCH_FIELDS = new String[] {"rowkey"};

private List<String> getIdsFromHive(String tableName, String whereBody) {
    ResultSet hiveResponse;

    try (HiveDataSearcher searcher = new HiveDataSearcher(HIVE_URL, HIVE_LOGIN, HIVE_PASSWORD)) {
        hiveResponse = searcher
                .setTableName(tableName)
                .setWhereBody(whereBody)
                .select(SEARCH_FIELDS);
    }

    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        while (hiveResponse.next()) { // in this place throw TTransportException
            ids.add(hiveResponse.getString(SEARCH_FIELDS[0]));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return ids;
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, the reason for this exception is closed the connection before closed the statement. So I suggest you to check whether you has maintain the connection correctly.

Here is my code, wish it will inspire you something:

Wrong code, close connection before closing the statement:

```
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        connection = HIVEUTILS.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl1");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (`id` int)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(1)");
    }finally {
        if (connection != null){
            connection.close();
        }
        if (statement != null){
            statement.close(); // exception occur here.
        }
    }
```

The correct order of closing is: close resultSet(if any) -> close statement -> close connection.

```
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        connection = HIVEUTILS.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl1");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (`id` int)");
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(1)");
    }finally {
        if (statement != null){
            statement.close(); // change the order
        }
        if (connection != null){
            connection.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This issue does not cause the exception stated in the question.